# How to check for collisions in a tilemap(Python/Pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

I am making an 2D RPG in Python/Pygame, and I have the map being made in a text tilemap. How can I check if the player comes in contact with a certain tile in the tilemap(In this case the wall).

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

fps = 60
playerX = 0
playerY = 0

grass = 0
wall = 1

tileSize = 32
mapWidth = 2
mapHeight = 2
displayWidth = mapWidth*tileSize
displayHeight = mapHeight*tileSize
tileMap = [
            [wall, grass],
            [wall, grass]
            ]

textures = {
            grass : pygame.image.load('data/grass.png'),
            wall : pygame.image.load('data/wall.png')

            }

player = pygame.image.load('data/player.png')

surface = pygame.display.set_mode((displayWidth, displayHeight))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
gameIsRunning = True

def gameQuit():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

while gameIsRunning == True:
    surface.fill(black)

    for row in range(mapHeight):
        for column in range(mapWidth):
            surface.blit(textures[tileMap[row][column]], (column*tileSize, row*tileSize, tileSize, tileSize))

    #Do collisions for wall in tilemap

    surface.blit(player, (playerX, playerY))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameQuit()

    keysPressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keysPressed[pygame.K_LEFT] and playerX >= 0:
        playerX -= 2
    elif keysPressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] and playerX <= displayWidth - player.get_width():
        playerX += 2
    elif keysPressed[pygame.K_UP] and playerY >= -28:
        playerY -= 2
    elif keysPressed[pygame.K_DOWN] and playerY <= displayHeight player.get_height():
        playerY += 2

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(fps)
```

I want the wall to act, well like a wall. And the player not being able to move through it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of checking collision, especially in a tilemap, is just a row of if... when the user tries to move the player.

Now, we'll consider that the dimensions of the player are 1, so we will be able to use its coordinates with the tiles' ones.

For example, in your case, instead of the four last if/elif, you could write as follows:

```
if keyPressed[pygame.K_LEFT] and playerX > 0:
    if tileMap[playerY][playerX - 1] is not wall:
        playerX -= 1
elif keyPressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] and playerX < mapWidth - 1:
    if tileMap[playerY][playerX + 1] is not wall:
        playerX += 1
elif keyPressed[pygame.K_UP] and playerY > 0:
    if tileMap[playerY - 1][playerX] is not wall:
        playerY -= 1
elif keyPressed[pygame.K_DOWN] and playerY < mapHeight - 1:
    if tileMap[playerY + 1][playerX] is not wall:
        playerY += 1
```

Then, after that, you'll have to redraw the entire screen (or only the previous and the current positions, but this will be harder to code), but I don't know `pygame` enough to tell you what functions to use...

Comment: I don't have player in the tilemap, I'm guessing it needs to be. So if I add player to the tilemap, how do I define playerX and playerY and how do I make the player move?

Comment: @OverRided I don't really know pygame, but instinctively I wouldn't do so. I think pygame supports transparency, so you create the tile representing the player using transparent background, and you draw the player on top of the tiles. For making him moving, you just have to repaint the screen, drawing the player in the next position

Comment: Well I tried those lines and I got an "IndexError: list index out of range" error. I'm guessing it's because playerX and playerY are being called as being in tileMap, so I tried just using playerX and playerY seperately, and tried tileMap[wall] with no luck. But anyway, thank you.

Comment: @OverRided What line does throw this error? My fault, I thought that the coordinates of player were the same than the tiles ones!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dusty\Dropbox\Dusty's Private Folder\Project City Tile\game.py", line 97, in <module>
    if keysPressed[pygame.K_LEFT] and playerX >= player.get_width() and tileMap[playerY][playerX - player.get_width()] is not wall:
IndexError: list index out of range @Spirine

Comment: Same error. The player isn't in tileMap so I'm pretty sure "tileMap[playerY][playerX - 1]" is the problem. Also, by printing wall I get "1", because that is the ID I define it as before the tileMap. Is there a way to get the rect/position of a tile in a tileMap? So I can check the collisions that way by using a rect of the player in a for loop or something. P.S I already am redrawing the screen

Comment: @OverRided I've tested it, and I've found where the IndexError came from: I thought that the `and` keyword was like the C `&&`, but it's not. To resolve this, you must add another nested `if` statement, instead of the third `and [...]`, see my edit.

Comment: I still get the same index error... here's my full code if it helps anything. http://pastebin.com/C7ETvjke @Spirine

Comment: @OverRided Sorry again, I'm recopying from my computer to a smartphone the code... In the previous code, a the second if statement had `PlayerX` instead of `PlayerY`, and the last one had `players`...

Answer (score 1):

In your keysPressed if loop, you might be able to get away with adding to the if another and that says something along the lines of (for a left key press...)if playerX-1 is not a wall AND playerX-2 is not a wall then move.

Comment: Do I need player in the tileMap to do this? And If I do, what do I need to change with movement and playerX and playerY?

Comment: @OverRided What does a line of code such as `print(tileMap[0][0])` print?

Comment: 1, because i'm guessing that's the value of the wall @Austin

Comment: @OverRided Does your player start at the 0,0 tile? Also are you able to do   `print(tileMap[playerX][playerY])`?

Comment: No and No. Currently the player is just blited on the screen. It's not in the tilemap @Austin

Comment: @OverRided Is the player a tile itself, just not on the map. For instance if playerX =0 and playerY = 0 is the player the 0,0 tile on top of the tilemap?

Comment: No it's about 50x50 and tiles are 32x32. I could resize it.

Comment: resizing the player tile to be the same size of grass and wall and then putting the player tile into the tile map might be an option. Otherwise you might have to do some rectangle collision, pygame actually i think has a function or method for this if I recall, but i am not sure about how to do rectangle collision with a tilemap, I am used to doing it with two rectangles, sorry!

Comment: I know how to check collisions with rectangles, but how would I find the rect of a tile in tilemap and how would I put the player in the tilemap, and move it etc.

Comment: Disclaimer: So this is all just ideas, none of what I am about to say is guaranteed to work. You can find the rect of a tile in the tile map by knowing which row and column its in and the fact that all the tiles are 32 by 32. So say you want the rect of the tile in row 0 column 0-> The rectangle is simply x1-0 x2-32 y1-0 y2-32. And you know the row and column from the playerX and playerY. I don't think putting the player into the tilemap is a great idea, because

Comment: say you have something like `tileMap = [
            [wall, player],
            [wall, grass]
            ]` The player would get repeated across your entire map as well as you wouldnt be able to see the grass under him. Honestly i am a bit out of my depth here having never used tile map's before.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to mess around with this tomorrow but I think if I have tilemap[0][0](example) as the position and 32 32 the width and height, I will be able to make a rect and check for collisions with the player.